# How to keep two sets of configs in sync with git

Tags: git

What is the best practice in keeping in sync two sets of largely overlapping but non-identical configs across computers?

I have my linux/emacs/... config under git. My config at work is largely the same as at home, but there are some small differences. Except those small differences I'd like to keep them fully in sync at all times.

If I create a "home" and "work" branch I'd have to commit each change that I want to sync two times (commit/switch branch/commit), right?

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

In my `setup/` directory I have a separate subdirectoy for each machine that I use. There I keep the files that differ between machines. There is also a subdirectory `shared/` where I keep the stuff that doesn't vary between machines.

So variation is done at the file level. One could of course use a macro processor to create a file out of several private and shared pieces, but up to now I haven't found it worthwhile to do that.

To install these configuration files I use my [`deploy`](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/deploy) program. This reads a file that tells it which files to install from the machine specific tree and which from the shared tree.